# Outlook Windows client: Inline reply format looks good in editor but gets wrong after sent

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

- See the email before sending out:

  [image]
- After I sent it to myself it became this:

  [image]
- In `Options > Mail > Replies and forwards` I have this:

  [image]

---

##### Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that the format of the original message is different from the format of your reply. For example, if the original message is in HTML format, and your reply is in plain text format, then your inline comments may not be preserved. You can try to change the format of your reply to match the original message.

Another reason could be that some add-ins that you have installed in Outlook are interfering with the inline comments. You can try to disable or uninstall any add-ins that you don’t need or use, and see if that solves the problem. You can also try to start Outlook in safe mode, which disables all add-ins, and see if the inline comments are included when you send a reply. To start Outlook in safe mode, press and hold the Ctrl key while you start Outlook.

A third reason could be that some settings in Outlook are prefacing your comments with some text or symbols that are not visible in your reply. You can check if you have enabled this option by going to File > Options > Mail > Replies and forwards, and see if you have checked the Preface comments with box. If you have, you can either uncheck it or change the text that you use to identify your comments.